# C3.js D3 fixed subchart scroll

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want exact scroll like attached image for c3 d3 charts.(example link:http://c3js.org/samples/options_subchart.html ) to this link i need to add fixed scroll as shown in the image.

I tried so many links in internet but didn't get the exact solution, Please help someone.
Thanks in advance. 
 [image]

Comment: please help somebody..........